# Implementing Serialization in a Class that contains an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm trying to serlialize a class I created, it's not working and for some reason I can't see the entire exception when I try to log it (in android), but that's not important...

I have a suspicion what it might be...

I haven't done java programming in many years... but now I seem to remember perhaps serialization is not completely automatic?

could someone please tell me what I have to do? point me in the right direction?

I have a class AccountList, I implemented serializable... it contains an arraylist of class Account ... I implemented serializable on AccountList and Account.. I mean just declared "implements Serializable"

but now I think I vaguely remember that if there is something like arraylist inside this AccountList class, then I must actually write some serialization code by overriding some methods in AccountList ?

what should I do?

Comment: No, `ArrayList` is also `Serializable`, so that's not the reason.

Comment: I figured it out.. I had some extra objects in there I forgot about - that I never intended to serialize.. I marked them with transient and that solved that problem... sort of like references to owner objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization is automatic as long as all the objects involved are `Serializable`. There are several mechanisms for tweaking how it works, but those are not likely to be relevant for you. Have a look at `Account` and `AccountList` and make sure all their member variables are `Serializable` too. And change your exception-handling code to improve the error display!

Answer (score 1):

An object is serializable if it implements `Serializable` and all of its non-transient and non-static fields are serializable. If a serializable object contains a collection, then that connection's elements must also be serializable.

Does you AccountList and Account contain collections who's elements are not serializable?